# Cannot open include file even when given the right path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been testing some stuff in Visual Studio after some time not working with VS, And I ran into a problem where I include a file and I get this error:

```
Cannot open include file 'spdlog/spdlog.h': No such file or directory
```

but I have the right path, in Project settings I have the right path set as an additional Include directory and the file is there. but the Thing is, when I take the file and move it one directory up and change the include path so that it now points one directory up (where the file is now) it suddenly works. Example:

File Path: Project/lib/spdlog/spdlog.h
Include directory: Project/lib
this Works

File Path: Project/lib/spdlog/spdlog/spdlog.h
Include directory: Project/lib/spdlog
This doesn't work

I don't want to include the lib directory since I have more libraries in it and it would just mess some stuff up, so I want to include every library (like spdlog for instance) separately. Does anyone know what might be causing the issue ? Also the error isn't shown when writing the code only when I try to build the Project.

Comment: Please add the info of how you include (the include line) to both of the information sets.

Comment: When you say you "move" the file one directory up, do you actually remove it from the original, or is it then in both locations?

Comment: Could it be that you have your project settings done for a certain configuration but not the one you are building?

Comment: @Yunnosch could you elaborate what you mean ? The Lib folder is in the root directory of the Visual Studio Project.

Comment: @AdrianMole I Copy the file, move it one directory up and remove the "old" file in the original location

Comment: @Zaiborg I Use Premake to automate this proess a bit (since it's complicated) and I made it in such a way that it isn't Configuration dependant, When I change the configuration it changes everything that needs to be changed

Comment: I suggest you try `#include "include/includedFile.h"` after setting the path.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT that's what I've been doing the whole time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing spdlog library.

I suggest you check out this [issue](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog).

For debian-like distros you should be able to download it via apt-get: `apt-get install libspdlog-dev`.